# Maven surefire fails with ClassNotFoundException: InPluginProcessDumpSingleton

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, java-17, jacoco-maven-plugin

After upgrading to openjdk 17, test cases are failing with error

**Exception in thread "closer-shutdown-hook" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/booterclient/output/InPluginProcessDumpSingleton
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$CloseableCloser.run(ForkStarter.java:209)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)**

Full trace

```
**Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was /bin/sh -c cd /builds/some-module && /opt/jdk-17.0.7+7/bin/java '-javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.8-runtime.jar=destfile=/builds/path/target/jacoco.exec,append=true -Duser.language=en -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxHeapSize=2g -Xmx2g --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.function=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.stream=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.regex=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter /builds/path/target/surefire 2024-03-14T15-01-53_612-jvmRun2 surefire7317203603829991286tmp surefire_113447887520135489243tmp
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 137
Crashed tests:
org.TestClass
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork (ForkStarter.java:748)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.access$700 (ForkStarter.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$1.call (ForkStarter.java:393)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$1.call (ForkStarter.java:370)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Exception in thread "closer-shutdown-hook" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/booterclient/output/InPluginProcessDumpSingleton
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$CloseableCloser.run(ForkStarter.java:209)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.InPluginProcessDumpSingleton
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 2 more**
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
           <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.8.8</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <append>true</append>
                       <!-- surefire (unit tests runner) arguments -->
                       <propertyName>surefireJacocoArgs</propertyName>
                       <includes>
                           <include>org.somepackage.*</include>
                       </includes>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
               <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
               <execution>
                   <id>jacoco-report</id>
                   <phase>test</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>report</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <!-- report output dir -->
                       <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-reports</outputDirectory>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*File.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                <rerunFailingTestsCount>5</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                <argLine>
                    ${surefireJacocoArgs} ${argline-add-open}
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Previously i was on openjdk 11, same used to work. suspecting issue is with maven surefire plugin incompatible with java 17. i even upgraded surefire to latest version still faced same issue

**Update 1**

After removing `useSystemClassLoader` flag, now i see another error  
 Process exit code --> 137 issue related to memory

```
ExecutionException The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was /bin/sh -c cd /builds/modules/module1 && /opt/jdk-17.0.7+7/bin/java '-javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.8-runtime.jar=destfile=/builds/modules/module1/target/jacoco.exec,append=true -Duser.language=en -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx5g --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.function=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.stream=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.regex=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter /builds/modules/module1/target/surefire 2024-03-14T10-28-32_626-jvmRun4 surefire8889132164816018609tmp surefire_1182817604224050150tmp
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 137
Crashed tests:
SomeTestClass
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.awaitResultsDone(ForkStarter.java:532)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkOnceMultiple(ForkStarter.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:321)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

Comment: How about removing `useSystemClassLoader` from the configuration with [`maven-surefire-plugin:3.2.5`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.2.5)? If that still fails, sharing a minimal example would be a good idea.

Comment: Upgrade jacoco to most recent version, upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to most recent version...remove propertyName from jacoco configuration, remove argLine from maven-surefire-plugin configuration... remove excludes, where are coming all those add-opens etc. on the shown command line? Do you execute the build on plain command line of from within your IDE?

Comment: @khmarbaise, i upgraded to latest surefire plugin, still faced same issue. i already mention same config used to work on older java 11. add-opens refer to a property just to open some packages(from reflection for mocking private members), as i see these are restricted in 17. Build executed from plan command line

Comment: A full working example would be helpful also I would say mocking private members sounds wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise, i have a large test suite,  cant point to one working example here.

Comment: @Naman, removed useSystemClassLoader flag too, now i see some other error. I remember i added this flag after i faced with a error with some class loader.

Comment: Now i'm facing error with process exit 137, may be my project test suite has memory issues or openjdk 17 jvm/gc has some issues for my specific test suite

Comment: Would not be easy to explain without a reproducible example or details over the subsequent issues faced.